# Obtener numeros de string (Int o float)

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo cadenas de string como las siguientes:

```
€14.5M, €50M, $14.8M, $$70.5M ,100M
```

Como puedo hacer para recorrer esos string y obtener el numero que hay en ellos, siendo enteros o float sin perder el .
Llegue a esto pero pierdo el punto por lo que 13.5 se convierte en 135

```
dato = '€14.5M'

simple_dream_team.Wage.apply(lambda x: ''.join([n for n in x if n.isdigit()]))

return = 145
```

Podria hacer un replace de simbolos como €, $ o la M a '' pero por lo que estoy viendo me esta llegando cualquier cosa por eso no lo aplico.

Comment: ¿Estás usando Pandas?

Comment: Si, disculpa, ahí lo agregue en las etiquetas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para los ejemplos que proporcionas podrías hacerlo funcionar siguiendo tu idea original mediante algo así:

```
nc = {'-', '+', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.'}
simple_dream_team.Wage.apply(lambda x: ''.join(n for n in x if n in nc))
```

No obstante no es ni muy eficiente ni muy robusto.

Si tienes tus cadenas en una Serie o en una columna de un DataFrame puedes usar una expresión regular junto a [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"Wage": ('€14.5M', '€50M', '$14.8M', '$$70.5M' ,'100M')})    
df["nums"] = df.Wage.str.extract(r"([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)", expand=False)
```

La expresión regular pasada a `pandas.Series.str.extract` tiene que tener definido al menos un grupo de captura  ya que cada grupo va a formar una nueva columna. De ahí los paréntesis en la expresión. Solo obtiene la primera coincidencia, en tu caso esto es lo único que necesitas, si una cadena puede tener más de una coincidencia y las necesitamos todas se puede usar [`pandas.Series.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas.Series.str.extractall).

Si quieres convertir la columna a tipo float directamente basta con usar `Series.astype` por ejemplo:

```
df["nums"] = df.Wage.str.extract(r"([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)", expand=False).astype("f", copy=False)
```

La salida es:

```
>>> df
    Wage    nums
0   €14.5M  14.5
1   €50M    50
2   $14.8M  14.8
3   $$70.5M 70.5
4   100M    100
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias. Lo aplique al DF y mi función solo recibe los números una sola vez seguido o antecedidos por símbolos por lo que el extract funciona perfecto

Answer (score 0):

Mira aqui te dejo un script que hace algo parecido a lo que necesitas. Utiliza el paquete 're' que es para Operaciones de expresión regular.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re


valores = ['€14.5M', '€50M', '$14.8M', '$$70.5M', '100M']

for valor in valores:
    cadena = re.sub("\D", "", valor)
    print (cadena)
```

Cuando UNICODE no se especifica, la bandera \D, coincide con cualquier dígito decimal; Esto es equivalente al conjunto [0-9]. Ojo es importante incorporar `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` al inicio de tu script ya que los caracteres € y $$ te arrojarán un error: `Syntax Error: Non-UTF-8 code starting with b'\x80' in file...`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero al hacerlo sobre 460.000 datos el for hace que sea lento, por eso en pandas lo aplica al conjunto y no linea por linea.

Comment: Es verdad! la solución de @FJSevilla es más rápida